# Resample into equidistant time based on multiple indices

Tags: pandas, time-series, resampling

I have a dataframe with some network flows similar to this

```
flow = {'date': ['2020-11-13 13:57:51','2020-11-13 13:57:51','2020-11-13 13:57:52','2020-11-13 13:59:53','2020-11-13 13:59:54'],
        'source_ip': ['192.168.1.1','192.168.1.2','10.0.0.1','192.168.1.1','192.168.1.1'],
        'destination_ip': ['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.1', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.2'],
        'source_bytes':[5,1,2,3,3]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(flow, columns = ['date', 'source_ip', 'destination_ip', 'source_bytes']).set_index('date')
```

Looks like this

```
date                | source_ip     | destination_ip| source_bytes
2020-11-13 13:57:51 | 192.168.1.1   | 10.0.0.1      | 5
2020-11-13 13:57:51 | 192.168.1.2   | 10.0.0.1      | 1 
2020-11-13 13:57:52 | 10.0.0.1      | 192.168.1.1   | 2
2020-11-13 13:59:53 | 192.168.1.1   | 192.168.1.2   | 3
2020-11-13 13:59:54 | 192.168.1.2   | 192.168.1.1   | 3
```

I would like to resample them into 1min ticks but also grouped by ip. Then source_bytes needs to be aggregated regardless if the ip is in either source_ip or destination_ip

Should become something like that. (Calculated manually. Hopefully did not do any mistakes here). For every minute all ip's should be represented but filled with zeros if there is no value.

```
ip          | date                  | source_bytes_sum
192.168.1.1 | 2020-11-13 13:57:00   | 7
192.168.1.2 | 2020-11-13 13:57:00   | 1
10.0.0.1    | 2020-11-13 13:57:00   | 8
192.168.1.1 | 2020-11-13 13:59:00   | 6
192.168.1.2 | 2020-11-13 13:59:00   | 6
10.0.0.1    | 2020-11-13 13:59:00   | 0
```

Here the same representation just 'grouped' by the ip

```
ip          | date                  | source_bytes_sum
192.168.1.1 | 2020-11-13 13:57:00   | 7
            | 2020-11-13 13:59:00   | 6
192.168.1.2 | 2020-11-13 13:57:00   | 1
            | 2020-11-13 13:59:00   | 6
10.0.0.1    | 2020-11-13 13:57:00   | 8
            | 2020-11-13 13:59:00   | 0
```

I started experimenting with the following but that only groups by source_ip and ignores destination_ip. Also it does not add zero values

```
grouped = df.groupby(['source_ip', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1min')])[['source_bytes']].agg(['sum'])
grouped

                                source_bytes
                                sum
source_ip   date    
10.0.0.1    2020-11-13 13:57:00 2
192.168.1.1 2020-11-13 13:57:00 5
            2020-11-13 13:59:00 6
192.168.1.2 2020-11-13 13:57:00 1
```

Comment: Have you looked into the resampling function in pandas ? [resample link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Comment: yes as shown in my example. But can't figure out how to combine the source_ip and destination_ip into the sampling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unpivot first by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), then use your solution with `Grouper` and for `0` values add [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = (df.melt(['date', 'source_bytes'], value_name='ip')
        .groupby(['ip', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1min')])['source_bytes']
        .sum()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='sum'))
print (df)
            ip                date  sum
0     10.0.0.1 2020-11-13 13:57:00    8
1     10.0.0.1 2020-11-13 13:59:00    0
2  192.168.1.1 2020-11-13 13:57:00    7
3  192.168.1.1 2020-11-13 13:59:00    6
4  192.168.1.2 2020-11-13 13:57:00    1
5  192.168.1.2 2020-11-13 13:59:00    6
```

Or use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with appended `source_bytes` to `MultiIndex` with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(['date','source_bytes'])
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='ip')
        .groupby(['ip', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1min')])['source_bytes']
        .sum()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='sum')
       )
print (df)
            ip                date  sum
0     10.0.0.1 2020-11-13 13:57:00    8
1     10.0.0.1 2020-11-13 13:59:00    0
2  192.168.1.1 2020-11-13 13:57:00    7
3  192.168.1.1 2020-11-13 13:59:00    6
4  192.168.1.2 2020-11-13 13:57:00    1
5  192.168.1.2 2020-11-13 13:59:00    6
```

EDIT: For use more aggregate function use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(flow, columns = ['date', 'source_ip', 'destination_ip', 'source_bytes'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])


df2 = (df.melt(['date', 'source_bytes'], value_name='ip')
        .groupby(['ip', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1min')])['source_bytes']
        .agg(['sum','min','mean'])
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .stack()
        .reset_index()
        )
print (df2)
            ip                date  sum  min      mean
0     10.0.0.1 2020-11-13 13:57:00    8    1  2.666667
1     10.0.0.1 2020-11-13 13:59:00    0    0  0.000000
2  192.168.1.1 2020-11-13 13:57:00    7    2  3.500000
3  192.168.1.1 2020-11-13 13:59:00    6    3  3.000000
4  192.168.1.2 2020-11-13 13:57:00    1    1  1.000000
5  192.168.1.2 2020-11-13 13:59:00    6    3  3.000000
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at your first solution but get the following output https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sGs5FrpjB5/

Comment: yes that looks much better. Just another question. If I want to extend this to more fields i.e `destination_bytes, source_packets` as well as more aggregates i.e `.agg(['sum','min','mean'])` what would I need to do for the index reset?

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly also by adding additional columns

Comment: Hi, I was just wondering how I could make sure that all the minutes between min(date) and max(date) are shown with zeroed values and each ip?

Comment: @Chris On phone only, but not sure what you think, maybe the best post new question.

Comment: Ie 13:58 is missing so there is a gap between some if the times. They should be filled with zero values so you get an equidistant time series. Might post another question